# Javascript - Updating String Values

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create a virtual deck of playing cards where one can pull a random card out of the deck.

The way I made this work is through a switch statement so that if a value of 'AH' is drawn, the image shown is that of a Card with Ace of Hearts. So far so good.

However, I am trying to implement a small feature so that a message is shown saying 'You drew Ace of Hearts. My (failed) attempt at accomplishing is the split variable 'AH' into 2 separate variables:

```
var drawnCardValue = 'A';
var drawnCardSuit = 'H';
```

Then convert 'A' to 'Ace' and 'H' to 'Hearts' using a switch statement:

```
function fullName(){
    switch(drawnCardValue){
        case 'A':
            drawnCardValue = "Ace";
            break;
        } //repeated for all values
    switch(drawnCardSuit){
        case 'H':
            drawnCardValue = "Ace";
            break;
        } //repeated for all suits
    }
```

When implementing the function above in my drawCard() function, as seen below:

```
function drawCard(){
    if(count < 52){
        drawnCard = deck.shift();
        showCard();
        var drawnCardValue = drawnCard.slice(0, -1);
        var drawnCardSuit = drawnCard.slice(-1);
        fullName();
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "You drew " + drawnCardValue + " of " + drawnCardSuit;
        count++;
    } else{
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Out of Cards";
    }
}
```

It is still displaying: You drew A of H

What is the reason for this? And how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide the full code or at least a link to it.

Comment: Please create working model or jsfiddle

Comment: Looks like you're never calling `fullName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code it looks like both the `fullName` and `drawCard` functions are reading/writing the `drawnCardValue` and `drawnCardSuit` variables  that are defined outside (i.e. in the outer scope).

However in the `draw` function you are creating new variables that are shadowing the ones in the outer scope.

```
var drawnCardValue = drawnCard.slice(0, -1); // <--- NEW VARIABLE
var drawnCardSuit = drawnCard.slice(-1); // <--- NEW VARIABLE
fullName();
```

This means that `fullName` will still process the unchanged variables in the outer scope.

Remove `var` to fix the issue:

```
drawnCardValue = drawnCard.slice(0, -1);
drawnCardSuit = drawnCard.slice(-1);
fullName();
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed the issue. Thanks Maluen!! Appreciate the feedback :)